# Hiding data from logs in Blue Prism

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I have this process where I read data from an excel file, everything works and the items are getting completed. I would like to make the data from each item not show up in the logs in my control room. I have encrypted the queue. On the stages I have "errors only" to show in the logs. Am I supposed to do anything else? It is not hiding the data.

Answer (score 0):

Got it I was not ticking the "Don't log parameters in this stage" box: My bad..